# Connecting different voltages in parrallel?

Tags: batteries

why I musn't I connect different voltages in parallel? also actually why I can connect them in parallel if they are "equal" .. why is that correct? 
Hi guys, why I musn't I connect different voltages in parallel? also actually why I can connect them in parallel if they are "equal" .. why is that correct?

Second question, why in digital logic for determining what's the function of any circuit it's sufficient to to find all the possibilities that leads to output =1 and since we create the function? is it because if we don't have "1" then it's definite 0 then the same function satisfied ?

Another thing and it's harassing me so much and please try to illustrate it more than simple you guess ! , what's harassing me is: 
lets assume I have square and its area is a*b=5. so if I want the half of the area of the square then at the sketch of the square we are making "line" at a/2 which this line mediate it to two halves, my question isn't the line itself occupy area between two halves?! what I assume that because the line itself occupy area, then area of half square should be = (a*b/2)+ epsilon(are of the line itself) but apparently that's wrong and I don't know why, any explanation please?

sorry about this thing but it's always chasing me and yet didn't get the answer.

thanks in advance.

Comment: There can be only one voltage between two points. And one question per question, unless they are tightly related.

Comment: One question per question, please. I answered the one in the title, but your second question should be a separate question, and your third one doesn't even belong on this site.

Comment: We assume hypothetical lines consume no area.

Comment: "Mustn't" is pronounced "musn't" but not spelled this way. and it is better to avoid duplicate "I" before and after a verb, so instead of "why I musn't I connect " why should  I not connect ... ?

Answer (score 3):

Let's explain it by looking at what happens in an example.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5oRL8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the above schematic, the ground-referenced voltage at A is 1V. That's simple enough, right?

Likewise, the voltage at B is 2V.

Now if we bring these together, what voltage is measured between ground and C? According to V1, it's 1V, but according to V2, it's 2V. It clearly can't be both at once; thus, it should be clear that this is a physical impossibility.

Comment: yet there is no such thing as a perfect voltage source.... even the grid.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 That's what I'm trying to point out here. It's a contradiction if you assume ideal voltage sources, so it's a physical impossibility. Sure, the question doesn't specify, but people asking questions this basic tend to be best helped by answers of how ideal components act. At least, I think so.

Comment: yes Rule #1 understand Ohm's Law.  Repeat until understood.  \$ V/R=I~~ or~~ ΔV/R=ΔI  ~~or~~  ΔV / 0Ω = ∞~ Amps\$  when ΔV≠0

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Don't let a mathematician hear you say that 1/0=∞.

Comment: same don't ever tell an EE that a real voltage source has Z=0 (lol)  that's why Maxwell ignored all the great German Mathematicians in his 1st book called A Treatise for ElectroMagnetism which he describes in his forward with more tact.  Even the Romans believed there was no such thing as 0.

Answer (score 0):

### Rule #1 understand Ohm's Law. Repeat until understood.

### V/R=I  or  ΔV/R=ΔI  or  ΔV/0Ω=∞ Amps  when ΔV≠0 and R=0

R=0 which never exists in nature !

The circulating current of parallel voltage sources with ESR total in a loop = Delta V/ESR

Thus is 10A with 100V with 1% load regulation each ESR is each 0.1 ohm then if V tolerance is 5% , circulating current is 10V/0.2ohms = 50A or 5kW on a 1kW supply.

Although if these were batteries, 1% difference may be OK as they equalize, but for regulated supplies they waste current.

[click here for Simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2043%0As%20448%2080%20512%2080%200%201%20true%0Aw%20416%2080%20448%2080%202%0Av%20448%20160%20448%2080%200%200%2040%203.6%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20448%20160%20448%20192%200%200.01%0Ag%20448%20192%20448%20208%200%0Ar%20544%20160%20544%20192%200%200.01%0Av%20544%20160%20544%2080%200%200%2040%203.7%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20544%2080%20512%2080%203%0Aw%20448%20192%20544%20192%200%0A403%20576%200%20704%2064%200%207_64_0_12546_3.7_0.0001_0_2_7_3%0A403%20576%20160%20704%20224%200%205_64_1_4354_0.0000762939453125_0.1_0_1_0.3125%0A403%20368%200%20496%2064%200%201_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_1_3%0A403%20576%2080%20704%20144%200%207_64_0_4353_5_6.4_0_2_7_3%0A)  [image]

But if load regulation = ΔV1/V [%] at Imax* Rmin=ΔV1

and voltage tolerance = ΔV2/V [%] at no load

Thus circulating current = rated current if Load regulation = 1/2 Voltage tolerance.  thus **they must be matched voltage [%] much less than [%] load regulation error.**

For Redundant current sharing often a 10% preload is necessary when the voltage error is nulled < 0.1% to avoid regulator instability from control system phase margin.

Comment: I edited my thread, see the last question and thanks for your answer!